# DCE in Gridelements not working (empty fields) - TYPO3 10.4

Tags: typo3, tx-gridelements, tx-dce

when i nest a DCE-Element inside a Gridelements-Container, the fields of the rendered DCE are empty and not shown in the frontend.

I tried a custom template to resolve it but couldn't.

Here is what i got so far:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<f:if condition="{children}">
    <div class="grid grid-onecol grid-layout-{data.layout} {f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, then: ' frame-space-before-{data.space_before_class}')}{f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, then: ' frame-space-after-{data.space_after_class}')}">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="grid-row row">
                <f:for each="{children}" as="columns" key="rowNumber">
                    <f:if condition="{columns}">
                        <div class="grid-col col-12">

                            <f:for each="{columns.101}" as="child">
                                <f:if condition="{child.data.CType}">
                                    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="tt_content.{child.data.CType}" data="{child.data}" table="tt_content" />
                                </f:if>
                            </f:for>
                            
                        </div>
                    </f:if>
                </f:for>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</f:if>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your dataProcessing options in the Gridelements TypoScript setup used for those containers.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/stable/Chapters/DataProcessing/Reference/Index.html

There are two switches

```
resolveFlexFormData
```

and

```
resolveChildFlexFormData
```

which can be used to activate or deactivate the automatic FlexForm resolving of the DataProcessor. By default they are both set to active.

Comment: I had the same problem and struggled with understanding wwhat to do. In the above case, you just have to disable it for ChildFlexForms. I did that globally. Seems to work, fingers crossed ;). 

`tt_content.gridelements_pi1.dataProcessing.10.default.options.resolveChildFlexFormData=0`

Comment: @Mateng Perfect, thank you!